# Invalid Syntax in a simple code

Tags: invalidation

I keep getting this error saying Invalid syntax and I'm really lost and don't know why !

```
def calculator():

def add(x, y):

    return x + y
def subtract(x, y):

    return x - y
def multiply(x, y):

    return x * y
def devide(x, y):

    return x / y
print("Select operation.")

print("1.Add")

print("2.Subtract")

print("3.Multiply")

print("4.Devide")

choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))

num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

if choice == "1":
    print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
    elif choice == ("2":)
```

Right after `elif` I can't seem to go through and I don't know why in my eyes everything seems fine . I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a calculator but I'm lost here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I put the code in fine order but it wont appeear so in the post im srry

Comment: Welcome to programming. The first thing you need to do is find out what programming language you are learning (looks like Python but I'm not an expert). Once you know it, please edit the question, add the appropriate tags and format code to make it readable. Thank you!

Comment: what language is it?

Comment: BTW, "Invalid syntax" can't be the complete information provided by your compiler or interpreter. It's normal that you still don't understand error messages but you must learn to do so, not discard them—error messages are there to help you write code!

Comment: This is the error im geting Alvaro SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I have only done a little Python but this should work.

```
if choice == "1":
print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
elif choice == "2":
print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The elif sentence appears to have bad indentation. That is important in python. I don't know if it is a typo in your question or in your code.

Also `("2":)` is incorrect, remove the parenthesis symbols.